# How to draw a map using GPS position and Raphael.js?

Tags: svg, raphael, d3.js

I am a complete newbie to SVG and Raphael.js or D3.js I have to draw some polygons that will represent areas on a map, I have their boundaries in GPS positions something like this

```
            <point>-51.48978803312559,-20.92831898046678,0</point>
            <point>-51.48978803310288,-20.93881598388512,0</point>
            <point>-51.43348803310235,-20.94831798048511,0</point>
            <point>-51.44478803314599,-20.91831598078533,0</point>
            <point>-51.43332332310254,-20.95131534854545,0</point>
            <point>-51.43978803310235,-20.92233431048519,0</point>
```

Do I need to translate this to SVG commands ? can't I use this GPS positions to draw it ?

I looked at the Docs and there is no mention about this anywhere, or information about how to parse it if there is no other solution.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the polygon on top of Google Maps, you can use their [Polygon drawing API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons) for that.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to draw them on empty space so I will have to use Raphael.js

Comment: I understand, only thought so because initially you used the Google Maps tag on your questions.

Comment: No problem, I removed the tag so there will be no more confusion.